# VB.net | Writing a REG_BINARY to the registry

Tags: vb.net, registry

I'm trying to write a REG_BINARY to the registry, but for some reason the second set of text is giving an error saying its expecting a }?

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\TEST", "KEY", New Byte() {86, 23, E3, 92, 1E, E8, 65, 07, D5, 12, 1E, E3, E3, E3, E3},RegistryValueKind.Binary)
```

How would I write that into the registry as REG_BINARY?

After ab it states cd expected a } after it?

**EDIT**

I'm Sorry for not mentioning...It really does make a difference to the question, the content I'm trying to write is HEX.

Comment: Looks like an attempt to write hex literals.  Use digits 0-9 and letters A-F only, append an H to make it hex.  Separate values with a comma.  So 12H and ABH are valid, "hi" certainly is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not legal VB.NET syntax for an array initialiser. You need to separate each array element value with a comma, e.g. `New Byte() {0,1,2,3,4}`. If you want to write hex values instead of decimal, use the `&H` prefix, e.g `New Byte() {&H0,&H1,&H2,&H3,&H4}`.